# Comparing expressions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, equality

```
-- | A very simple data type for expressions.
data Expr = Const Int | Add Expr Expr deriving Show

-- | 'Expression' is an instance of 'Num'. You will get warnings because
--   many required methods are not implemented.
instance Num Expr where
    fromInteger = Const . fromInteger
    (+) = Add

-- | Equality of 'Expr's modulo associativity.
instance Eq Expr where
    (==) = error "Not yet implementd: (==)"


-- | A test expression.
testexpression1 :: Expr
testexpression1 = 3 + (4 + 5)

-- | A test expression.
testexpression2 :: Expr
testexpression2 = (3 + 4) + 5
```

Yes, it's homework. So I'm looking for hints, no solutions. I need a start idea here.

Comment: should `testexpression1` be equal to `testexpression2`? If yes it seems like you might want to evaluate them and compare the results

Comment: btw: hints are hard to pack into an answer - maybe you should post this at reddit instead?

Comment: Yes, they should be equal. Okay, maybe you are right. Sorry :)

Comment: If it's modulo associativity, you might want to consider either using a representation that's invariant under associativity, or converting to such a representation to compare. Consider a list of expressions, for example.

Comment: right now (only +) associativity is implied if you just look at the outcome (`12 == 12` of course) - so evaluate the expressions and use `Int`s `Eq` instance

Comment: Hint: define a function `eval :: Expr -> Int`; and then define a function called `reduce :: Expr -> Expr; reduce = Const . eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Equality modulo associativity" means that you're looking for the following (correct me if I'm wrong!):

```
(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)
```

i.e. the grouping on `Add` doesn't matter, but the *order* does. Think about how you can directly encode this into your data types. For instance, the above would be represented like so:

```
Add (Add (Const a) (Const b)) (Const c) (1)
==
Add (Const a) (Add (Const b) (Const c)) (2)
```

You can visualize these as trees:

```
(1)
        Add
       /   \
      /     \
    Add   Const c
  /     \
Const a Const b

(2)
         Add
       /     \
      /      Add
     /     /    \
Const a  Const b Const c
```

My typical approach when dealing with recursive data types like this is to visualize them as trees and try to see a pattern. Do you see a pattern? In what way is (1) the same as (2)? How can you encode this?

Comment: At which position in the code I have to do sth? According to your question: I think they both have the same "deepness", same start and they are mirrored in a way.. I am not sure, if I get it. I have big problems with such new datatypes, which are implemented by the teacher. :\

Comment: @fuuman Try to visualize the trees for (a + b) + (c + d) and a + (b + (c + d)) as well; these are also equivalent modulo associativity but don't have the same depth! Also, try to think about what kind of common operations you might perform on trees and you might start to see a solution forming.

Comment: I am able to visualize that. I think they are the same at the leafs. From the left to the right the leafs say "a b c d". From this logical point of view it's no problem. I have problem with the codec in Haskell. I dont know how to express that in the (==) = ... :\

Comment: @fuuman Why not try collecting the leaves in some other container and checking to see if the sequences are the same? You understand the logic, that's 90% of the battle.

Comment: Thank you for your great support and motivation! :) Can you give me the left side of the (==)? Are there any pattern that I can match on the right side? How can I check if an input is a leaf or just another "Add"?

Comment: @fuuman You can pattern match on both sides of `==` with any pattern of your `Expr`, namely `Add` and `Const`.

Comment: Tried sth like "(==) ((Const a1) + (Add b1 c1)) ((Add a2 b2) + (Const c2)) = 
     a1 == a2 && b1 == b2 && c1 == c2" But it didn't work at all. Don't think that this is even close to a solution. Giving me a "Parse error in pattern: (Const a1) + (Add b1 c1)". I just have no idea and learnyouahaskell is no help on that case.. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56725/discussion-between-benjamin-kovach-and-fuuman).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want both `testexpression1` and `testexpression2` to be equal, then you can proceed like this:

```
toEList :: Expr -> [Int]
toEList e1 = reduce e1 []
  where reduce :: Expr -> [Int] -> [Int]
        reduce (Const x) acc = x:acc
        reduce (Add e1 e2) acc = ??? -- Think about how you will accumulate all
                                     -- the values from `Add` to the `acc`.
```

This function will evaluate any `Expr` to `[Int]`. Now try to implement the instance from that function:

```
instance Eq Expr where
  (Const x) == (Const y) = ???
  e1 == e2 = ??? -- You have to apply `toElist` function and sort them in both
                 -- `e1` and `e2` cases to test their equality.
```

Comment: No. You don't want `2 + 3` to be equal to `4 + 1`. That's not "equality modulo associativity" however you spin it.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I misunderstood the question. Have updated it appropriately.